# UI suggestion: Where to place MoveUp/Down buttons

Tags: c#, winforms, user-experience

It is ugly but I can't find a better place to put Move-up and Down buttons.
What is your suggestion?

[image]

Comment: You might want to ask this [here](http://ux.stackexchange.com) instead.

Comment: You *might* have better luck on a UX-specific site: http://ux.stackexchange.com/ maybe?

Comment: You can try expanding the table to the right, remove the comment, and align the buttons vertically with the `[Cancel]` button.

Answer (score 2):

I would say remove them and make it drag and droppable :)  Of course that isn't as intuitive to the user, but maybe you could have a label that says you can drag them to move them.

Answer (score 1):

Position of buttons are right.

For a more eye catching UI use up arrow and down arrow from Webdings/Wingdings font.

BTW this quesion is more suited for [here](https://ux.stackexchange.com/).(https://ux.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 1):

Just remove them, they are superfluous.  The user can already directly click the item, can use the up/down arrow keys and has a scrollbar.  That's enough.

Not only is it unnecessary, it is actually inferior.  Because the key won't repeat unless the user hammers the mouse button on it and it steals away the focus from the list.  There are workarounds for those problems but that's just code you shouldn't write in the first place.

Comment: But the ORDER of the items in the spreadsheet is important to the user. When he clicks MoveUp, the whole row moves one row up, it isn't actually for navigation on the spread rows.

Comment: Well, sure, then you need them.  This was entirely undiscoverable from the UI presentation btw.  At least consider labeling the button "Move item up" or putting them in a GroupBox labeled "Move item" and just an arrow icon for the button.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can remove text (move up, move down) - arrows are intuitive for people. Also consider how Microsoft implemented same feature in `Edit columns` dialog for grid:

[image]

BTW the best option IMO is drag-and-drop rows (no buttons at all). But you should somehow provide to users information (cursor, border, tooltip), that it is possible..